# Find the remainder when divided by $(x-1)^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the remainder when $f(x)=x^6+2x^5-3x^3+2x^2+x-1$ is divided by $(x-1)^2$

Using division algorithm 
$f(x)=g(x).q(x)+R$   ...........(1)

$g(x)=(x-1)^2$ and $R=rx+s$

Putting $x=1$ in (1)
We get $r+s=2$ .....(2)

Since the two factors are same we can't get a equation in $r$ and $s$ like (2)

It makes it difficult to solve any idea?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do long division, but you know that
$$
f(x)=(x-1)^2q(x)+ax+b
$$
Thus $f(1)=a+b$, which means $a+b=2$. Next
$$
f'(x)=2(x-1)q(x)+(x-1)^2q'(x)+a
$$
Can you compute $f'(1)$?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the long division：

[image]